# AuthorizationHandler unexpected behavior when reading request Body

Tags: .net-core

In a .NET Core 6 application, when calling a specific endpoint, sometimes I get a http 403 error, sometimes not (given the same body, same headers, same config, same everything).

Here are some relevant code sections :

`Startup.cs`:

```cs
// Startup file, Configure method :
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
var appSettings = Configuration.Get<AppSettings>();

app.UseCors(builder => builder
    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000", "http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:8080")
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowCredentials()
);
    
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseSwaggerAuthorized();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "My API"); });
app.UseNoCacheMiddleware();
app.UseMyExceptionMiddleware();

app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseSession();

if (appSettings.Hangfire.enabled)
{
    app.UseHangfireServer();
    app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
    {
        Authorization = new[] { new MyHangfireAuthorizationFilter() }
    });
}

lifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(OnAppStopped);

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.Use(next => context =>
{
    context.Request.EnableBuffering();
    return next(context);
});

app.UseEndpoints(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<MyHub>("/myHub");
    routes.MapControllers();
});
```

`MyController`:

```cs
// relevant endpoint method : 
[HttpPost("calendarChanges")]
[Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin,Admin,SpecificUser,AnotherSpecificUser")]
[Authorize(Policy = MyPolicies.CanChangeCalendar)]
public IActionResult CalendarChange([FromBody] CalendarChangesDto changes)
```

`SecurityConfiguration.cs`:

```cs
// in ConfigureAuthorization method :
options.AddPolicy(MyPolicies.CanChangeCalendar,
                policy => { policy.Requirements.Add(new CalendarChangeRequirement()); });
```

`MyCalendarChangeAuthorizationHandler.cs`:

```cs
public class MyCalendarChangeAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CalendarChangeRequirement>
{
        private readonly IMyManager _myManager;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly ILogger<MyCalendarChangeAuthorizationHandler > _logger;

        public MyCalendarChangeAuthorizationHandler(IMyManager myManager,
            IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, ILogger<MyCalendarChangeAuthorizationHandler> logger)
        {
            _myManager = myManager;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
            MyCalendarChangeRequirement requirement)
        {
            MyDto my;

            var request = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;
            request.EnableBuffering();

            try
            {
                request.Body.Position = 0;
                using var memStream = new MemoryStream();
                request.Body.CopyToAsync(memStream);
                memStream.Position = 0;
                var body = new StreamReader(memStream).ReadToEnd();
                _logger.LogInformation(body);
                var calendarChange = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CalendarChangesDto>(body);

                if (calendarChange == null || calendarChange.someId <= 0)
                {
                    context.Fail();
                    _logger.LogWarning($"Message could not be parsed to {nameof(CalendarChangesDto)}");
                    request.Body.Position = 0;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }

                // Rest of non relevant code
        }
}
```

Sometimes the body variable in `MyCalendarChangeAuthorizationHandler.HandleRequirementAsync` would be null. Sometimes not. For the exact same HTTP request. Meaning the parsing would return a null object and therefore call `context.Fail();`

I cannot reproduce the issue locally (so I cannot debug it).

I suspected that some action filter or middleware would read the body without buffering enabled. But the added `requestDelegate` that `enableBuffering` for each request shows that this was not the issue.

I have to admit I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: Why you are not awaiting `request.Body.CopyToAsync(memStream);` ? This might be an issue here really. In theory if you are not awaiting it, by the time you try to deserialize - the stream might be empty, might be not, which matches your behavior

Comment: There's an issue in the `HandleRequirementAsync` method. `CopyToAsync` should be awaited to ensure its completion before attempting to read the stream. Use `await request.Body.CopyToAsync(memStream);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Nikita Chayka , the issue was resolved by adding `.Wait()` call :

`request.Body.CopyToAsync(memStream).Wait();`